# Need to add all the difference values but for a specific index value range

Tags: python

I have a data frame:

I have to calculate all the differences but separately for each event. In the data frame, you can see that after index 8 index 12 starts which means the start of a new event and that difference should be calculated separately. So This means as the difference between index_col is 4 the new event starts and that difference should be sum separately.

So the sum of events should be like this e.g

index_col 1-8 sum of Difference should be 20.96 (belongs to the first event)
index_col 12-17 sum of Difference should be 16.17(belongs to the second even)
and so on ...

index_col Depth(nm) Load(µN)    Time (s)    Difference

```
1   42.478033   432.482376  5.460979    8.70957
2   44.217959   432.163277  5.461261    1.73993
3   44.517313   432.764691  5.461824    3.36262
4   44.602024   433.754851  5.462669    2.37831
5   44.452232   434.808104  5.463514    1.8221
6   44.785705   435.698639  5.464358    1.1552
7   44.008191   436.724050  5.464922    1.02758
8   44.104820   438.753727  5.466611    1.04814
12  39.918249   390.597846  5.476275    7.61717
13  40.939905   391.229950  5.477120    2.66319
14  40.709209   392.333573  5.477965    1.99305
15  40.975959   393.208349  5.478810    1.88325
16  40.415786   395.135862  5.480218    1.00294
17  40.748377   396.057784  5.481062    1.13622
21  45.101152   441.052546  5.554368    5.64005
22  43.096024   442.489659  5.554931    2.13311
23  44.581075   442.264911  5.555213    1.48505
24  43.757947   443.295160  5.555776    2.34133
25  44.020544   444.209317  5.556621    2.15143
26  44.457026   445.121651  5.557466    2.2784
27  44.332075   446.131261  5.558310    1.36814
28  43.853956   447.344522  5.559155    1.0139
32  38.420457   381.697812  5.462362    5.80165
33  39.247295   382.417916  5.463206    2.51963
34  38.910364   383.542124  5.464051    1.67136
38  45.939504   467.899009  5.564736    6.58783
39  44.251143   469.194422  5.565299    1.40849
40  46.242257   468.823029  5.565581    1.99111
41  45.032736   469.930914  5.566144    1.95164
42  45.540791   470.765236  5.566989    2.50574
43  45.520035   471.821972  5.567834    1.91457
44  45.593076   472.835489  5.568678    1.24077
45  45.267980   474.618237  5.570086    1.05416
46  45.238412   475.640147  5.570931    1.038062
49  38.193023   392.286042  5.490368    8.13389
50  41.444420   391.411630  5.490650    3.2514
```

Comment: Please add the code you wrote so far.

Comment: and your sample as plain text, please.

Comment: I tried some methods but none of them is working.. I have added the data as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

The way you add the data as plain text is very unhelpful. It would be much easier and faster if you add the data in the form `index_col = ...`, `load = ...` and so on.

That aside, this is my code:

```
index_col = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 32, 33, 34, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 49, 50]
depth = [42.478033, 44.217959, 44.517313, 44.602024, 44.452232, 44.785705, 44.008191, 44.10482, 39.918249, 40.939905, 40.709209, 40.975959, 40.415786, 40.748377, 45.101152, 43.096024, 44.581075, 43.757947, 44.020544, 44.457026, 44.332075, 43.853956, 38.420457, 39.247295, 38.910364, 45.939504, 44.251143, 46.242257, 45.032736, 45.540791, 45.520035, 45.593076, 45.26798, 45.238412, 38.193023, 41.44442]
load = [432.482376, 432.163277, 432.764691, 433.754851, 434.808104, 435.698639, 436.72405, 438.753727, 390.597846, 391.22995, 392.333573, 393.208349, 395.135862, 396.057784, 441.052546, 442.489659, 442.264911, 443.29516, 444.209317, 445.121651, 446.131261, 447.344522, 381.697812, 382.417916, 383.542124, 467.899009, 469.194422, 468.823029, 469.930914, 470.765236, 471.821972, 472.835489, 474.618237, 475.640147, 392.286042, 391.41163]
time = [5.460979, 5.461261, 5.461824, 5.462669, 5.463514, 5.464358, 5.464922, 5.466611, 5.476275, 5.47712, 5.477965, 5.47881, 5.480218, 5.481062, 5.554368, 5.554931, 5.555213, 5.555776, 5.556621, 5.557466, 5.55831, 5.559155, 5.462362, 5.463206, 5.464051, 5.564736, 5.565299, 5.565581, 5.566144, 5.566989, 5.567834, 5.568678, 5.570086, 5.570931, 5.490368, 5.49065]
difference = [8.70957, 1.73993, 3.36262, 2.37831, 1.8221, 1.1552, 1.02758, 1.04814, 7.61717, 2.66319, 1.99305, 1.88325, 1.00294, 1.13622, 5.64005, 2.13311, 1.48505, 2.34133, 2.15143, 2.2784, 1.36814, 1.0139, 5.80165, 2.51963, 1.67136, 6.58783, 1.40849, 1.99111, 1.95164, 2.50574, 1.91457, 1.24077, 1.05416, 1.03806, 8.13389, 3.2514]

df = pd.DataFrame({'index': index_col, 'depth': depth, 'load': load, 'time': time, 'difference': difference})

sum_diff = []
start = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i == len(df) - 1:
        end = i+1
        sum_diff.append(sum(df['difference'][start:end]))
    else:
        if df['index'][i] + 1 != df['index'][i + 1]:
            end = i+1
            sum_diff.append(sum(df['difference'][start:end]))
            start = end
            
print(sum_diff)
```

Output:

```
[21.24345, 16.295820000000003, 18.411409999999997, 9.99264, 19.69237, 11.38529]
```

I checked if the calculation is correct by doing this manually:

```
print(sum(df['difference'][0:8]))
print(sum(df['difference'][8:14]))
print(sum(df['difference'][14:22]))
print(sum(df['difference'][22:25]))
print(sum(df['difference'][25:34]))
print(sum(df['difference'][34:36]))
```

and yes, I got the same output:

```
21.24345
16.295820000000003
18.411409999999997
9.99264
19.69237
11.38529
```

Answer (score 0):

And elegant solution would be using groupby the dataframe based on the index_col differences and construct a dict for flexible use of sum. Take an empty dataframe and use it for the storage of the summed results.

You can do as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
result = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['event_no', 'sum'])

grouped_dict = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['index_col'].diff().gt(1).cumsum())))

for index in grouped_dict:
    result = result.append({'event_no': index+1, 'sum': grouped_dict[index]['difference'].sum()}, ignore_index=True)
```

And this will give you exactly what you want:

```
   event_no        sum
0       1.0  21.243450
1       2.0  16.295820
2       3.0  18.411410
3       4.0   9.992640
4       5.0  19.692372
5       6.0  11.385290
```

**What does df.groupby(df['index_col'].diff().gt(1).cumsum()) do?**

The `diff()` simply calculates the difference between consecutive indices in `df['index_col']`. The `gt(1)` returns whether each element in the `df['index_col'].diff()` is greater than 1 or not. the `cumsum()` then sums these `boolean` results. As index `0-7` is `False`, `cumsum` is `0` for each of these indexes. Then index `8` is `True`, So `cumsum` becomes `1` and remains same for the rest of the consecutive indices as they return `False` for `gt(1)`.

The calculation goes in the same way for rest of the consecutive segments. So for `df.groupby()` we get inputs of groups of `0's` to `5's` as follows:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
5
5
```

Hence group by is done based on these `5` values for your given input.

Hope that's clear now!

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. Just to understand the code in detail can you please explain what exactly '''gt(1).cumsum()'' mean. As in the output, I can see that this way we can group the data on index bases but I am confused about this part. Thanks

Comment: @AdnanFareed I've updated my answer and added the explanation, hope it helps!